# Inserting IndexPath into NSSet objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to insert IndexPath values into NSSet? basically Im trying to insert indexPath into my NSSet which is a set of all the turnedGreenCells into my CollectionView, but for some reason it doesn't work :\
Here's my Code:
ViewController.m

Edit: I added all the code to make it easier.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
//#import "CollectionViewTest-Swift.h"
#import "CustomCollectionViewCell.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"



@interface ViewController ()<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, ImpressionStalkerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@property NSArray *indexPathsOfCellsTurnedGreen_Arr;
@property NSMutableSet *indexPathsOfSeenCells;

@property ImpressionStalker *impressionEventStalker;




@end

@implementation ViewController
{
}



@synthesize Collection_view;




- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.impressionEventStalker = [[ImpressionStalker alloc] initWithMinimumPercentageOfCell:0.70 collectionView:Collection_view delegate:self];
    
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.myViewController = self;
    
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //    [impressionEventStalker stalkCells];
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}



// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL_ID" forIndexPath:indexPath] ;
    
    //    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", indexPath.row];
    
    [cell configure:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", indexPath.row] configure: NO];
    
    //    cell.cellBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    
    //    if ([_indexPathsOfCellsTurnedGreen_Arr containsObject:indexPath]) {
    //        cell.cellBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    //    } else {
    //        cell.cellBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    //
    //    }
    
    if ([_indexPathsOfSeenCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.cellBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    } else {
        cell.cellBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        
    }
    
    return cell;
}


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake( [ [UIScreen mainScreen]bounds ].size.width - 40, 325);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20);
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}



- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [(CustomCollectionViewCell*)cell startTimer:^{
        [self.impressionEventStalker stalkCells];
    }];
    
    
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [(CustomCollectionViewCell*)cell stopTimer];
}



- (void)sendEventForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath * _Nonnull)indexPath {
    
    CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell*)[Collection_view cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    
    
    //    [_indexPathsOfCellsTurnedGreen_Arr arrayByAddingObject:indexPath];
    //    [_indexPathsOfSeenCells setByAddingObject:indexPath];
    [_indexPathsOfSeenCells setByAddingObject:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)_indexPathsOfSeenCells.count);
}



// A func which sends all the seen cells to the server:.
- (NSSet*)sendStalkDataToServer {
    
    return _indexPathsOfSeenCells;
}




@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *Collection_view;

- (NSSet*)sendStalkDataToServer;

@end
```

Comment: A better way is to put a BOOL flag into the data model.

Comment: @vadian What do you mean? I don't have any data model only a class with a function that sends those indexPaths but I added "prints" there and they do get all the indexPaths also sending them. in that code that i've just posted I just want to make sure that the NSSet is not empty :)

Comment: First of all, you need a mutable set `NSMutableSet`. Also, did you actually initialize that property?

Comment: @Sulthan I added all my code :)

Comment: You probably have a class with properties to be displayed in the collection view. In this class add a BOOL property to indicate if the cell is *turned on*. Then in `cellForItemAt` set the color depending on the flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSSet` is immutable. `setByAddingObject` creates a new immutable set, therefore, you would have to assign the result to the property:

```
self.indexPathsOfSeenCells = [self.indexPathsOfSeenCells setByAddingObject:indexPath];
```

However, you should ideally use a mutable set, that is, `NSMutableSet`.

With a mutable set you could simply:

```
[self.indexPathsOfSeenCells addObject:indexPath];
```

Also note that your set is never initialized, therefore it is `nil` the whole time.

You have to put:

```
self.indexPathsOfSeenCells = [NSMutableSet set];
```

somewhere.

Comment: Oh didn't know that set is immutable in Objective-C :) btw I declared it like this: NSMutableSet *indexPathsOfSeenCells;